# Read info.plist in swift macOS library app

Tags: swift, macos, class-library

I am building a Library of classes in macOS swift. I created an empty Info.plist file in the root of the app folder and added a single entry (LibraryPath). Now I want to read the contents of the plist file. I've tried the following code, but it not finding the file. The last print statement just prints "None".

```
    func getInfoPlist()-> [String: Any]?{
    print("in getInfoPlist")
    
    var config: [String: Any]?
            
    if let infoPlistPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Info", withExtension: "plist") {
        do {
            let infoPlistData = try Data(contentsOf: infoPlistPath)
            
            if let dict = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: infoPlistData, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any] {
                config = dict
                return config
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    print(config?["LibraryPath"] ?? "None")
    return nil
    }
```

Comment: FYI - you don't to get the path, create data, and use PropertyListSerialization. Just use `var config = Bundle.main.infoDictionary`.

Comment: Interesting... when I ran your code, it indeed returned data from a standard app info.plist file (it had 42 entries) but appears to be from my unit test code. I do not have a plist in that folder, so where would it pick up that file?